# How i can collect array's values as number?

Tags: arrays, swift

i want from tableview to collect MyArray's as value like

Swift:

```
let total = UILabel()

var MyArray = ["2", "9", "33", "4"]

total.text = ?? // i want result be like this [2+9+33+4] = 48
```

and if add some value or remove some the result change

i hope i delivered right question and i hope i get the right answer

Comment: Start thinking about the first step (conversion of strings to numbers). What if the array is `["2", "wot?", ""]` ?

Comment: i think about that and thank u for your observation and i'm working on it, and i came up with that code **var: [NSNumber] = ["3", "6", "64"] **

Comment: Just a note on complexity with all of these answers: you shouldn't be doing the reduce in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Make one function that converts your array into models for the cell. This can be done with O(n) complexity.

Comment: This question is dubiously similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412203/how-i-can-collection-arrays-value-as-number#comment99430336_56412203), did you create a new account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. With `reduce` to sum up the values and ignore non-integer values

   ```
   total.text = String(myArray.reduce(0, {$0 + (Int($1) ?? 0)}))
   ```
2. With `NSExpression` if the array contains only string representations of integers. `joined` converts the array to `"2+9+33+4"`

   ```
   let additionExpression = NSExpression(format: myArray.joined(separator: "+"))
   total.text = "\(additionExpression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil)!)"
   ```

Comment: Use `Double` instead of `Int`

Comment: @arunsiva There is no reason if all values are integers.

Comment: But the given array is sample data. Mostly when calculating total there will be double value

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through your array, using conditional binding, if the value is invalid, e.g "hello", it won't enter the condition.

```swift
var result = 0

for element in MyArray { // MyArray should have the first letter lowercased and have a more meaningful name.
    if let number = Int(element) { // or NSNumber, Double, etc...
        result = result + number
    }
}

total.text = "\(result)" // consider naming it totalLabel
```

Comment: Totally valid, but I would suggest against loops like this, in circumstances for which existing functional methods are so perfectly fitting.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `myArray` elements type from `String` to `Double` using `compactMap`. Then add the elements using `reduce` method. Then convert the result to string to show in label.

```
var myArray = ["2", "9", "33", "4", "wot?", ""]
total.text = String(myArray.lazy.compactMap{ Double($0) }.reduce(0, +))//48.0
```

Comment: 1) You don't need the `( ... )` if you're using trailing closure syntax. Either omit them (`compactMap { Double($0) }`), or use the method as a closure directly (`compactMap(Double.init)`) 2) use a lazy collection to avoid the allocation for the intermediate result of `compactMap`. `let sum = myArray.lazy.compactMap{ Double($0) }.reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps::

1. **Calculate the total.**

   Consider:

   ```
   let array = ["200", "900", "33", "4"]

   let total = array
       .lazy
       .compactMap { Double($0) }
       .reduce(0, +)
   ```

   Note, unlike other suggestions, I’m refraining from placing this in a single line of code (although one could). The goal of functional programming patterns is to write expressive yet efficient code about which it is easy to reason. Placing all of this onto one line is contrary to that goal, IMHO, though it is arguably a matter of personal preference.
2. **Setting the text of the label.**

   When setting the text of the label, it’s very tempting to want to just do `String(total)`. But that is not a very user-friendly presentation (e.g. the sum 1,137 will be shown as “1137.0”). Nor is it localized.

   The typical solution when displaying a result (whether numbers, dates, time intervals, etc.) in the user interface is to use a “formatter”. In the case of numeric values, one would typically use a `NumberFormatter`:

   ```
   let formatter = NumberFormatter()
   formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
   label.text = formatter.string(for: total)
   ```

   For a user in the US, that will show “1,137”, whereas the German user will see “1.137”. So each device sees the number presented in a format consistent with the users’ localization preferences.